# Why do people generally not tell others where their new jobs are?

Tags: new-job, quitting

Several of my coworkers who have moved to another company all have kept quiet about what company exactly they are going to. They put in their 2 weeks notices, and for the most part, everyone around knew that, except where they were going to work. Not sure if this simply a trend here at my workplace, or if there is a strategic reason for this. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Did you ever ask where they were going to?